# Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am getting this error.
I know there are a lot of similar question, still I didn't find anything useful (probably my fault).

```
function connect(){
    $host = 'localhost';
    $db = 'db1';
    $user = 'user';
    $pwd = 'userpwd';
    return new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $db) or die('Cannot connect to database');
}

$dbconnection = connect();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';
$queryResult = $dbconnection->query($sql);
```

This last line is returning to me said error.
It is a very simple function, still I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `var_dump($dbconnection)`?

Comment: Any [connection errors](http://php.net/mysqli.connect-error)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running into an operator precedence issue. Your `return` is actually returning the boolean value of `new ... OR ...`, not the object you just instantiated. Try:

```
$con = new mysqli(...) or die(...);
return $con;
```

instead.

Followup:

```
function foo() {
   return 'foo' or die('failed');
}
function bar() {
   return false or die('failed');
}

var_dump(foo()); // outputs "bool(true)", not 'foo'
var_dump(bar()); // script exits with 'failed'
```

The return is catching the result of `foo OR bar`, and returning a boolean true/false. The OP's connect statement WORKED (or it would have die()'d). That returned object was then `or`'d and produced a boolean true result, which was then `return`ed.

Comment: Maybe I haven't had enough coffee yet but I'm not sure I understand. Why does splitting out the assignment and return functions into their own line do anything? If his connection is failing shouldn't his script die() and not have a chance to produce the error message? Ex http://codepad.org/tC5AXzMZ - my non-existant 'someMethod' doesn't get touched.

Comment: @Mike Again, precedence. `return ($foo or $bar)`, but `($foo = $bar) or $baz`.

Comment: Got it, surprised I've never run into that before but I guess I don't use a lot of conditions in my return statements. Thanks Marc and deceze

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use function 
instead instantiate the mysqli connection directly.
This works.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);

    $host = 'localhost';
    $db = 'dbname';
    $user = 'root';
    $pwd = 'password';
    $connect = new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $db) or die('Cannot connect to database');


$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';
$queryResult = $connect->query($sql);

foreach ($queryResult as $user) {
        echo $user['id'];
}
```